# How to increment variable inside single/double quote in jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on button, the div will add with dynamic id. How it will be done?

**Html:**

```
@php
$loop = 1;
@endphp
@foreach($Products as $list)
<div id="add_{{$loop++}}">
</div>
@endforeach
<button onClick="add_more()">Add</button>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    var count = 0;
function add_more() {
    count++;
var html = '<div id="product_attr_'+count+'">New Div</div>';
$('#add_'+count).after(html);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing IDs is a lot more trouble than it is worth, especially when you start removing items.

Just use classes and insert after the last of the class.

```js
function add_more() {
  var html = '<div class="product">New Div</div>';
  $('.product').last().after(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">One</div>
<div class="product">Two</div>
<button onClick="add_more()">Add</button>
```

Comment: You're right but in my case i can't use classes because of unique ids.